# Combine the data of two tables using SQL Pivot and joins for a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report to find the number of users subscribed to the notification type.

I am stuck with subqueries because if these two tables

> Table 1
>
> NotificationMaster

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Email |
|  2 | Push  |
|  3 | Call  |
+----+-------+
```

> Table 2
>
> NotificationPreference

```
+------------+------------------+------------+--------------+
| ResourceID |  NotificationID  |  IsChecked |  AccountID   |
+------------+------------------+------------+--------------+
|         23 |                1 | 1              1         |
|         36 |                2 | 0              2         |
|         45 |                3 | 1              3         |
|         23 |                1 | 0              1         |
|         36 |                2 | 1              2         |
|         45 |                3 | 0              3         | 
|         23 |                1 | 1              1         |
|         36 |                2 | 0              3         |
|         45 |                3 | 1              3         |
+------------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

> Expected Output
>
> Notification Vs Resource Count

```
+----------+-------+------+------+
| Accountid Email | Push | Call |
+----------+-------+------+------+
| 1        |  2    |    1 |    2 |
+----------+-------+------+------+
```

> Other Tables
>
> AccountName

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Blues |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Jazz  |
+----+-------+
| 3  | Rock  |
+----+-------+
```

> ResourceNames

```
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| Resource |      Name      | AccountID |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
|       23 |          MJ    |         1 |
|       36 |          Paul  |         1 |
|       45 |          Jay Z |         3 |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

> Progress Till Now

```
SELECT A.ID
,A.Name
    ,count(R.id) AS 'Total Resource Count'
    ,(SELECT count(DISTINCT np.resourceid)
    FROM NotificationPreference np
    INNER JOIN NotificationMaster nm ON np.notificationid = nm.id
    WHERE np.accountid = A.ID
        AND nm.id = 1
 ) AS 'Email'
FROM AccountName A
LEFT JOIN [ResourceNames] R ON A.ID = R.[AccountID]
LEFT JOIN NotificationPreference np ON np.resourceid = R.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
,A.Name
```

Comment: @Xaphas there is an `Expected Output` but doesnt match the query OP is working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pivot use conditional `COUNT()` :

```
 SELECT Accountid
     ,  COUNT( CASE WHEN nm.Name = 'Email' THEN 1 END ) as Email
     ,  COUNT( CASE WHEN nm.Name = 'Push' THEN 1 END ) as Push 
     ,  COUNT( CASE WHEN nm.Name = 'Call' THEN 1 END ) as Call
 FROM NotificationPreference np
 JOIN NotificationMaster nm
   ON np.NotificationID  = nm.id
 GROUP BY Accountid
```